# Python Splinter cannot click button

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I am running through the Splinter tutorial located here: http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#

The code I am using:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://google.com')
browser.fill('q', 'chicago pizza')
button = browser.find_by_name('btnG')
button.click()
```

Every time I try to get my code to click the search I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    button.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\__init__.py", line 546, in click
    self._element.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

I have used `browser.find_by_id`, `browser.find_by_tag`, `browser.find_by_text` and none have worked, all giving me the same error.

I am running python 2.7.8 Firefox v 54.0.1 (32-bit) and have selenium installed.
Any idea of how to fix this? I think it may have to do with my geckodriver.

I would like to solve the problem and not have to work around it by say switching web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Everything worked fine except you have entered wrong name of `button`.

Here is the working code

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://google.com')
browser.fill('q', 'chicago pizza')
button = browser.find_by_name('btnK')
button.click()
```